# Java IO buffer navigation

Tags: java, io

I read from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/streams.html) that a big difference from Java IO and Java NIO is that in the first we can navigate from the data only after the creation of a buffer (I think with, for example, a BufferedInputStreamer object).
In the second the data read from a channel is stored directly in a buffer.

Please, can anyone write some code snippets that show how to navigate, back and forth from an old IO buffer and the same translate with the new IO API?

Thanks.

Comment: Both Api's are significantly different and can't just be translated 1 to 1. It's an entirely different api and method of working.

Comment: And what you mean by 'navigate from the data' is anybody's guess. Please clarify.

Comment: Google is your friend - there is pleanty of material out there - such as this dzone artikel http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-nio-vs-io

Comment: @EJP, for navigation I mean a method to move in the buffer changing the position of a cursor and thus start to read or write from there.

Comment: @xdevel2000 In IO you can use seek() for the streams which support it. For NIO you can use position() if the buffer also contains the data you need.

Comment: @Peter, do you mean to use RandomAccessFile seek() method?

Comment: @xdevel2000 That is one example, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Example of skipping 1024, reading the next 1024, and seeking back to 0;

nio:

```
int i=1024;
Path p = Paths.get("./","file.txt");
SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(p, StandardOpenOption.READ);
sbc.position((long)i);
ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(i);
sbc.read(bf);
byte[] b = bf.array();
sbc.position(0L);
```

io:

```
int i=1024;
File f = new File("./file.txt");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
bis.mark(i*2);
bis.skip((long)i);
byte[] b = new byte[i];
bis.read(byte[] b);
bis.reset();
```